# How to compare a datetime type in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

So I have a column in my DB on SQL Server that is a datetime.  I want to do this simple select statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM Res
Where dateSubmit='6/17/2010 5:01:26 PM'
```

`dateSubmit` is a datetime data type and my database has a row where dateSubmit is 6/17/2010 5:01:26 PM

However, when I execute this statement it returns null.

Comment: My SQL Server recollection is that you need to specify the date as year-month-day.

Comment: I tried that as well, however it didn't work and when I look at the actual values in the datetime columns it is in the month-day-year-time format

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think SQL Server keeps more digits of precision than it is displaying.

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Res 
Where dateSubmit between '6/17/2010 5:01:26 PM' and '6/17/2010 5:01:27 PM'
```

Comment: Yup, that did the trick. Thanks a lot.  It must be keeping track of the milliseconds as well or something.

Comment: you really want `dateSubmit>='6/17/2010 5:01:26 PM' and dateSubmit<'6/17/2010 5:01:27 PM'`, because `BETWEEN` will give you rows `<=` the end range value, and you just want `<` the end value.

Comment: In my experience, SQL Server behaves better if you use ISO standard datetime strings:  `'2010-06-17T17:01:26'`  If you're using a parameter, be sure to strip the milliseconds before attempting this.

Comment: @KM, very good point. I had thought that the end of the range was excluded, but I just checked the docs for BETWEEN and you are correct.

Comment: @Toby, I prefer ISO format too, it's unambiguous. I didn't think it was relevant to the question though.

Comment: SQL Server's datetime does indeed keep track of milliseconds, aka fractional seconds, up until three positions.

The details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

Comment: @Mark Ransom, that is why I **never** use `BETWEEN`, it is more clear to just use `>=` or `>`, and `<=` or `<`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the hour: minute: sec part and you will never get exact sec that’s why you’ll get null.
Try to use

```
SELECT * 
FROM Res
Where DATEDIFF ( day , dateSubmit , '6/17/2010 5:01:26 PM' )=0
```

For more information look to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx#GetDateandTimeDifference)

The “day” could be replace by anything else as “DatePart” see the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Res
Where DATEDIFF ( minute, dateSubmit , '6/17/2010 5:01:26 PM' )=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Strip the time if that is irrelevant

Dateadd(d, datediff(d,0,getdate()),0)

Comment: I need the time unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

When I try running something similar in my version of SQL Server (2005), it works as expected.

Try taking out the PM and using 24 hour format instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Res 
Where dateSubmit='6/17/2010 17:01:26'
```

Comment: I tried that before and just tried again, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it should work.  You might try
SELECT * FROM Res Where cast(dateSubmit as nvarchar) ='6/17/2010 5:01:26PM'

Comment: this will negate index usage, it is better to cast the string to a datetime, that way an index can be used.  Also, CONVERT is better for taking `datetime` to string, you can specify a format.

Comment: Also - when I try this it doesn't match, as the cast as nvarchar returns the month as a string as well - i.e. "jun"

Comment: Yeah, convert would be better